# How to write a T-sql Case statement with multiple conditions with Coalesce

Tags: sql, case-statement

I'm trying to run a query/case statement. I want 'No' if the field contains the word "None" or if the field is blank... else 'Yes'. But this statement is giving me 'Yes' for blank fields...

```
   CASE
   WHEN VOB.INSTRUC_CONC LIKE '%NONE%' OR VOB.INSTRUC_CONC IS NULL THEN 'NO'         
   ELSE 'YES'
   END AS 'INSTRUCTIONS'
```

Comment: `OR VOB.INSTRUC_CONC = ''`

Comment: `case` _expression_. (It returns a value.)